# what is use of generic declaration in object declaration (eg. HashMap<Integer,Integer> )

Tags: java

In below example I have tried creating a generic ref `hm` referring to newly created `HashMap` having type `<Integer,Integer>`. But even if I add string values through `hm` reference it is allowing. If ref have eg. `hm1` below it is throwing error at compile time only.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
hm.put("hello", "HashMap"); // why it is allowing even if the object created passed <Integer,Integer> else what is significance of <Integer,Integer> on object declaration

HashMap <Integer,Integer> hm1;
hm1 = hm;
hm1.put("adfasf", "adff"); // throws error
```

So my question is why it is allowing to add element having different data type even if the object created passed `<Integer,Integer>` else what is significance of `<Integer,Integer>` on object declaration?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: You are casting to a raw type, so all the generics are lost.

Comment: `HashMap hm;` -- You have no reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
hm.put("hello", "HashMap");
```

Generics in Java happen only at compile-time, they have absolutely no effect at runtime.

This means that at runtime a `HashMap<String, String>` is the same kind of object as a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`.

All that generics do is tell the compiler to check the declared types for sanity (and for historical reasons this is opt-in, you can leave generics off).

In your example, the type of the variable is just the raw type `HashMap` (without any generic types). As such, the compiler will not perform the type checks for keys or values. (And you will have gotten a warning about that).

```
HashMap <Integer,Integer> hm1;
hm1.put("adfasf", "adff"); // throws error
```

As opposed to `hm`, your `hm1` does have the generic types, and the compiler will check it.

Note that it does not "throw an error", though (that would be a runtime thing), but it just fails to compile. If you managed to compile this code, it would run without error (as you witnessed when you accessed the same object through `hm`). You would get an error only when you tried to get an Integer out of your map again (because the typecast would fail at runtime).

Comment: Thanks. But then what is the use of allowing generics in `new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()`

Comment: So that you get an error if you did stuff like `Map<String, String> h1 = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()`. The compiler will reject that. What you wrote will generate a warning, too.

Comment: It is true that `new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()` is a bit redundant if you also have the types on the left side. That's why Java lets you write `new HashMap<>()` instead. Note that it still has the "diamond" in there. It's not a raw type, it's the inferred generic type.

Comment: A lot of this stuff is historic cruft. In modern Java, make sure you avoid using "raw" types and heed all the type-safety warnings.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> HashMap hm = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
> hm.put("hello", "HashMap"); // why it is allowing even if the object created passed <Integer,Integer> else what is significance of <Integer,Integer> on object declaration
> ```

Because `hm` is typed `HashMap`, not `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`. You've assigned a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to it, but just given its type as `HashMap`. Since `HashMap` accepts any object for both key and value, strings are acceptable and the code compiles. (It also runs, because of type erasure.)

> ```
> HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm1;
> hm1 = hm;
> hm1.put("adfasf", "adff"); // throws error
> ```

That fails to compile because you've told the compiler what `hm1` will contain; the type of `hm1` is `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`, not just `HashMap`, and so the compiler knows that putting strings into it is not okay.